# Show that $\alpha^2=0$ or $1$ for every $\alpha$ in the ring, $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(x^2, y^2, 2)$ and determine those elements with $\alpha^2=0$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show that $\alpha^2=0$ or $1$ for every $\alpha$ in the ring, $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(x^2, y^2, 2)$ and determine those elements with $\alpha^2=0$.

Previously, I found that the structure and the characteristic were

Structure: $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(x^2,y^2,2) \cong \{ax+bxy+cy+d | a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{Z}_2\}$

Characteristic: $\text{char}\, \mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(x^2,y^2,2)=2$

How would I prove this using the structure and characteristic? Or can't I?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2, y^2, 2)$ makes no sense since $y \not\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$

Comment: Sorry typo on my part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A:=\mathbb Z[x,y]/(x^2,y^2,2)$ has characteristic $2$, we have for each $\alpha,\beta\in A$, that $(\alpha+\beta)^2=\alpha^2+\beta^2$ and $(\alpha\beta)^2=\alpha^2\beta^2$. Thus, to prove that for each $\alpha\in A$ we have $\alpha^2=0$ or $1$, it is enough to prove it for $\alpha=1,x,y$. This can be done by direct calculation.

Moreover, suppose $\alpha=a+bx+cy+dxy$ is such that $\alpha^2=0$. Then, we see that $(a+bx+cy+dxy)^2=a=0$, so $\alpha^2=0$ if and only if $\alpha\in(x,y)$.

---

In other words, the map $A\to A:\alpha\mapsto\alpha^2$ is a ring homomorphism with image $\mathbb Z_2$ and kernel $(x,y)$. This induces the isomorphism $A/(x,y)\cong\mathbb Z_2$.